# Xcode 8 Beta 4 Swift 3 - "round" behaviour changed

Tags: swift3

I have the following simple extension to `Double`, which worked fine in everything up to Xcode 8 beta 3

```
public extension Double {
    public func roundTo(_ decimalPlaces: Int) -> Double {
        var v = self
        var divisor = 1.0
        if decimalPlaces > 0 {
            for _ in 1 ... decimalPlaces {
                v *= 10.0
                divisor *= 0.1
            }
        }
        return round(v) * divisor
    }
}
```

As of Beta 4, I am getting "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable" on the `round` function in the return - has anyone got any clues?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is due to a naming conflict with [the new rounding functions](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0113-rounding-functions-on-floatingpoint.md) on the [`FloatingPoint`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/protocol/FloatingPoint/) protocol, `round()` and `rounded()`, which have been added to Swift 3 as of Xcode 8 beta 4.

You therefore either need to disambiguate by specifying that you're referring to global `round()` function in the `Darwin` module:

```
return Darwin.round(v) * divisor
```

Or, even better, simply make use of the new rounding functions and call `rounded()` on `v`:

```
return v.rounded() * divisor
```