# Swift 3 Migration - Double Extension rounding issue

Tags: double, rounding, swift3, xcode8

I'm migrating our codebase to Swift 3 and I've come across a compilation issue that I can't explain or fix.

I have a method in a `Double` extension that rounds the `Double` to a certain number of digits:

```
public func roundToPlaces(places: Int) -> Double {
    let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
    return round(self * divisor) / divisor
}
```

For example: 
`12.34567.roundToPlaces(2)` should return `12.35`. However, I'm getting a compilation issue for the `round` method used in this extension. It's saying that I `Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable`.

[image: compilation error image]

Any ideas on what's going on here? How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 8 Beta 4 Swift 3 - "round" behaviour changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767635/xcode-8-beta-4-swift-3-round-behaviour-changed)

Comment: Shouldn't rounding `12.34567` return `12.35` ?

Comment: my mistake...yes, 12.35. editing now...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've fixed the issue. Changing `round(self * divisor)` to `(self * divisor).rounded()` resolved the compilation issue.

Comment: I had to do: (self * divisor).rounded() with parenthesis