# Extension Double Round to places Swift 3

Tags: swift

I have the following extension

```
extension Double {
    func roundToPlaces(places:Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return (self * divisor).rounded / divisor
    }
}
```

When I update it to Swift 3, it doesn't work. I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39512671/swift-3-migration-double-extension-rounding-issue), but I got

`Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type '_' and 'Double'` error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot a pair of brackets: should be `rounded()` instead of `rounded`:

```
extension Double {
    func roundToPlaces(places:Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
```