# How to use a mutable variable in CGFloat Extension in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently upgrading a forked Framework to Swift 3.

Working Swift 2 Code:

```
public extension CGFloat {

    var roundToNearestHalf: CGFloat {
        return round(self * 2)/2 
    }
}
```

In Swift 3, the return throws the `compiler error : Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable`.

I was able to find tons of documentations why a method of a Struct need to to mutable. But so far I'm not able to find a solution for a variable.

If I enter the keyword mutating, the compiler throws the error: `Expected declaration`

```
public extension CGFloat {

    var roundToNearestHalf: CGFloat mutating {
        return round(self * 2)/2
    }
}
```

[image]

My research on this issue is, that the code seems to be misplaced - so it needs to be within a function.

```
public extension CGFloat {

    mutating func roundToNearestHalf() -> CGFloat {
        var roundToNearestHalf: CGFloat {
            return round(self * 2)/2
        }
    }
}
```

Now the compiler complains about the `*``

[image]

Research on that issue brought me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338573/rounding-a-double-value-to-x-number-of-decimal-places-in-swift/27339287) Thread, that suggests to use the `round` function the way I'm trying too.

Since this code obviously worked till Swift 3, I'd like to know why it does not anymore. Why does a var has to be declared as mutable now? And how do I need to declare the var `roundToNearestHalf` now? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to (nor can you) mark anything as `mutating` – you just need to say `return Darwin.round(self * 2)/2` or `(self * 2).rounded()/2`

Comment: `(self * 2).rounded()/2` did it, thank you very much for your efford

Comment: @Hamish feel free to answer

Comment: I don't think that I've said anything that I haven't said in [my answer to the linked Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38767820/2976878). If you think that it solves your problem, then feel free to accept the dupe mark :)

Comment: I can't accept it, but I have upvoted the Q&A answer

Comment: Chat was a miss-click, but I have literally no option to accept the flag

Comment: Huh, weird. I was always under the impression that the OP gets prompted whether they want to accept a suggested dupe mark. Never mind, we can just wait for someone to come along with a dupe hammer.

Comment: all i am able to accept are edit. whatever you got the well earned upvote. i also have been researching for about 30 minutes, but i haven't come up with the idea to google for `round` itself... was googleing for mutable vars of strucs and whatever... guess this Swift3 stuff will cost me some more sleepless nights...^^

Comment: `passion for Swift, and a tolerance for Objective-C.` tolerance for Objective-C lol xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immutable things now usually have past participle names.

joined(), reversed(), rounded() methods that support fluent chaining

where before there were lots of free functions in present tense that took an argument grammatically in accusative case

like join(x), round(x)... they grammatically look very similar, which made round look like it would change x even though it didn't. Now it does :)

Now everything is way more streamlined, that's the big API change everybody is talking about :)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer and explanation

Comment: You're very welcome :)

Comment: For collections that I write, I use the names plus, with, and without for add, put, remove btw. These are not past participles but still very clear about creating a new thing in stead of modifying the existing instance en lieu.