# Getting error while rounding a double value with 3 digits precision in swift 3

Tags: ios, double, swift3

I'm using this extension to round a double value with 3 digits precision.

```
extension Double {
    var DigitsPrecision: String {

        return String(Double(round(1000*self)/1000)) //round the double with 3 digits precision
    }
}
```

It worked perfectly on swift 2.2 but when I migrated my project to swift 3.0 its throws this error

```
Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 8 Beta 4 Swift 3 - "round" behaviour changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767635/xcode-8-beta-4-swift-3-round-behaviour-changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the new `rounded` method on the value itself:

```
extension Double {
    var digitsPrecision: String {
        return String(Double((1000 * self).rounded() / 1000))
    }
}
```