# Calling the built-in function with the same name as a custom function

Tags: swift, rounding, built-in

I have the following code to round a value to any nearest number:

```
func round(_ value: Double, toNearest nearest: Double) -> Double {
    let roundedValue = round(value / nearest) * nearest
    return roundedValue
}
```

However, I get the following complaint because I use the same name for this method as the builtin one:

```
Missing argument for parameter 'toNearest' in call
```

Is there a way to get around this? i.e. `builtin round(value / nearest)`?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `Darwin.round(value / nearest)`?

Comment: FYI Having multiple functions with the same name that are distinguished by their signature is called function overloading.

Comment: Related: [Swift 3.0: compiler error when calling global func min<T>(T,T) in Array or Dictionary extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39602298/2976878) & [Xcode 8 Beta 4 Swift 3 - “round” behaviour changed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38767635/2976878)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the following answer:

- [How to round a Double to the nearest Int in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350977/how-to-round-a-double-to-the-nearest-int-in-swift/41488326#41488326)

most Darwin/C rounding methods are now readily available as native Swift methods, for types conforming to `FloatingPoint` (e.g. `Double` and `Float`). This means that if you are set on implementing your own rounding method using the same logic as in your question, you can use the [`rounded()` method of `FloatingPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint/2295900-rounded), which make use of the `.toNearestOrAwayFromZero` rounding rule, which is (as described in the linked answer) equivalent to the Darwin/C `round(...)` method.

Applied to modify your custom `round(_:toNearest:)` function:

```
func round(_ value: Double, toNearest nearest: Double) -> Double {
    return (value / nearest).rounded() * nearest
}
```